# How to select content language on Google Play Movies

Tags: google-play-store, languages, localization

I'm in Germany and I want to download movies in English from the Google Play store to watch my Android tablet, however I can only get movies in German. How can I get the English versions?

Comment: Contents are selected based on your location, and (maybe) your device's language settings. If the latter is a criterium you could check by setting your device's language to English. I'm not 100% sure if this works, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Unfortunately device language does not influence movies language. Tried on my device.

Comment: I'learning German and I wanted exactly the opposite.

Comment: I confirm what @Filippo Mazza said. All my settings are to German, mobile device and all Google accounts, but because I live in the Netherlands I get the movies in English.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the build.prop settings on a rooted phone with something like `ro.com.google.clientidbase.ms=android-uscellular-us` i think or maybe `ro.product.locale.region=US`

Answer (score 1):

At least in new Google Movies app (mine is V3.8.8) you can find Audio Language preference in Settings: it allows to Play videos in video's original language or US English when available.

Hope it helps.

Comment: what does when available mean.  Every movie i check is only in german

Comment: I mean that not every movie has a US English audio version or there are other restrictions (that I however ignore). I am in France and most French movies do not provide an English version... :/ (so the option is of course not available )